# Count pair of start and closing character within a string?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, string-search

Let's say I have the string:

> You are pretty `<`lady`>` but that `<`girl`>` is prettier `<`than`>` you.

Sorry about the English but how could I count how many <> there are in the above text ?

I know I could do:

```
int count = message.Length - message.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Length;
```

But that would count even if the text was like this:

> Hey `<<<<` you `<<<<<` how you doing `>>>`

When in fact I just want to count the pairs of <> so the count goes by one when it finds a starting < and ending > and should only starting counting when < is found.

Comment: in this case `<<<>>>` result should say 1 or 3?

Comment: Should count 1 because it each <> works for embracing a single content only so when you use it multiple times inside one it will not turn into anything else but if u have `<<<>>> asdas <>` then it should count 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about doing it like this. Basically you should only count the > if you have encountered a < at some time before. Or said in another way. You stack up <'s, and then you use one of them each when you encounter a >.

```
string test = "You are pretty <lady> but that <girl> is prettier <than> you.";

int startcount = 0;
int paircount = 0;
foreach( char c in test ){
  if( c == '<' )
    startcount++;
  if( c == '>' && startcount > 0 ){
    startcount--;
    paircount++;
  }
}
//paircount should now be the value you are after.
```

**EDIT**

I thought that <<<>>> should count 3 not 1, so then you need a quick fix above. For it to count <<<>>> as only 1, change to this

```
string test = "You are pretty <lady> but that <girl> is prettier <than> you.";

bool foundstart = false;
int paircount = 0;
foreach( char c in test ){
  if( c == '<' )
    foundstart = true;
  if( c == '>' && foundstart ){
    foundstart = false;
    paircount++;
  }
}
//paircount should now be the value you are after.
```

Comment: +1. But it should be noted that this will count `you are <so <pretty>> lady` as two which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: of course, that's easy to fix by only increasing `paircount` when startcount is zero.

Comment: Oyvind thanks for the reply is there a way to make this in short with linq or would not be worthed compared to the foreach efficiency ?

Comment: Isak Savo - Should be fixed by my edit before you posted your comments. Still problems with the approach?

Comment: Prix - As much as I love LINQ, not all tasks are suited for LINQ. I'm sure you can do this using LINQ (probably by using Aggregate), but the code will be more complicated and unreadable (and also less performant, but that will probably not matter if you don't have a gigantic string). LINQ has many used, but this is not one of them IMO.

Comment: Oyvind thanks for the response, another quick question \n is also considered as a char right ? Wanted to catch it as well but am not sure.

Comment: Yes, '\n' is one single char just like 'a' or '<'

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int count = b.Split('<').Count(t => t.Contains('>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

```
        string test = "You are pretty <<<lady>>> but that <girl> is prettier <than> you.";

        int found = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++) {

            if (test[i] == '<')
            {
                found++;
            }
            else if (test[i] == '>'&&found!=1)
            {
                found--;
            }
            else if (test[i] == '>'&&found==1) {
                count++;
                found = 0;

            }else continue;

        }
        return count;
```